# how to split every integer in txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, split

So I have a txt which has 2 lines as

```
move 30 20 50
move 60 2 54
```

and I split those two lines into two elements into a list like this

```
codereader = 'deneme.txt'

file_handle = open(codereader, "r")
text = file_handle.read().splitlines()
terminal_reader = "{}".format(text)

print(terminal_reader)
```

and it gives me the solution underneath

```
#['move 30 20 50','move 60 2 54']
```

but also I have to put every number to different tuples like 30 and 60 has to go to list called speed. 20 and 2 has to go to list called distance and the last numbers has to go to a list called time. So at the end the solution has to be like this.

```
speed_values = ['30', '60']
distance_values = ['20','2']
time_values = ['50','54']
```

but if I add another move into the txt code has to append the last move's numbers into the end of the lists.
I dont know how to seperate them individually like this.

Comment: For tuples you should use round brackets. Square brackets are for lists.

Comment: sorry my bad. just assume that I'm talking about lists. btw I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the values in `text` and split each one of them:

```py
line_items = [line.split() for line in text]
```

Now you have `[['move', '30', '20', '50'], ['move', '60', '2', '54']]`.

To group values on the same index you can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```py
line_items = zip(*[['move', '30', '20', '50'], ['move', '60', '2', '54']])
```

That will give you an iterator that looks like: `[['move', 'move'], ['30', '60'], ...`

Now you can assign them into variables.

```
In [1]: a, b = zip([1, 2], [3, 4])

In [2]: a
Out[2]: (1, 3)

In [3]: b
Out[3]: (2, 4)
```

Comment: I will use that method. thank you so much